# How to fix the unmounted component in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

How to fix the error: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

here' the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        let ignore = false;
        setTimeout(() => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                try {
                    setLoading(true);
                    setError({});
                    const response = await getLatest();
                    if (!ignore) setData(response['data']);
                } catch (err) {
                    setError(err);
                }
                setLoading(false);
            };
            fetchData();
        });
        return () => {
            ignore = true;
        };
    }, []);
```

The problem here is when I click the home page while loading the data and click the room page. then the error will appeared. How to fix on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clean up your timeout on unmount, otherwise, it tries to execute your hooks to update the internal state of the component after it goes out of scope (I assume functions like `setLoading` and `setError` are from a React hook).

To do so, put the output of `setTimeout` in a variable and then call `clearTimeout` in the function you return from `useEffect`. That's the clean up function and it's run when the component gets unmounted. So you need something like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  ...
  const timeout = setTimeout(...)
  return () => {
    ...
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
}, [])
```

See the docs for more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect